# Best practices for handling variable size arrays in c / c++?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

If I have an array of a fixed size depending on how it is defined and used, I typically use one of two ways to reference it.

Array type 1: Since it is a fixed size based on a define, I just use that define in all my loops referencing it.

```
#define MAXPLAYERS 4

int playerscores[MAXPLAYERS];

for(i=0;i<MAXPLAYERS;++i)
{
.... do something with each player
}
```

Array type 2: Since this array can grow as items are added to it, I use the sizeof to count the number of entries in it. The size would be converted to a constant by the compiler so there shouldn't be any runtime penalty to doing it this way.

```
typedef struct
{
    fields....
}MYSTRUCT_DEF;

MYSTRUCT_DEF mystruct[]={
   {entry 1},
   {entry 2},
   {entry 3...n}
   };

 for(i=0;i<(sizeof(mystruct)/sizeof(MYSTRUCT_DEF));++i)
 {
 ..... do something with each entry
 }
```

Is there a more elegant solution to handling processing of arrays without going past the end or stopping too early. Thoughts? Comments?

Comment: Note that this is not a variable size array in the usual sense of the term (where the number of elements varies at runtime).

Comment: If you are using C++ you should really be using one of the STL containers. Otherwise remove the C++ tag. Whilst C++ and C are semi portable, they are not the same thing.

Comment: I'm slightly annoyed by the "c/c++" formulation, because most answers here are for C++, not C...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work for both of your cases, regardless of array element type:

```
#define ARRAY_COUNT(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof((x)[0]))

...

struct foo arr[100];
...

for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_COUNT(arr); ++i) {
    /* do stuff to arr[i] */
}
```

Comment: And, this will work even in the first case where it's just a fixed size array of int. By using an ARRAY_COUNT macro, you avoid the problem where you change the size of the array (by using a different #define) but forget to change all the loops.

Comment: Be very careful not to pass to ARRAY_COUNT a pointer, because then you will get a wrong answer.

Answer (score 6):

In C++ just use the vector class.

If you can't for some reason then there are macro implementations of what you want.
See this answer for a set of macros from winnt.h that work in C and even more safely in C++:

[Can this macro be converted to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95500/can-this-macro-be-converted-to-a-function#95714)

Answer (score 5):

Use the _countof macro of stdlib.h

[From this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175773(VS.80).aspx):

```
// crt_countof.cpp
#define _UNICODE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tchar.h>
int main( void )
{
   _TCHAR arr[20], *p;
   printf( "sizeof(arr) = %d bytes\n", sizeof(arr) );
   printf( "_countof(arr) = %d elements\n", _countof(arr) );
   // In C++, the following line would generate a compile-time error:
   // printf( "%d\n", _countof(p) ); // error C2784 (because p is a pointer)

   _tcscpy_s( arr, _countof(arr), _T("a string") );
   // unlike sizeof, _countof works here for both narrow- and wide-character strings
}
```

Comment: of course, the leading underscore tells you exactly how portable it is.  If you only need to target a single compiler, that's fine, but it can bite you later if you need to port to other compilers (even if not other platforms).

Comment: Actually - I was thinking of simply stealing it to put in my existing macro.  I like the symmetry with sizeof().

Comment: That's a nice one - not really really portable, but still kind of

Comment: This is cpp only?

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly common to see C code like

```
struct foo {
    ...  /* fields */
};
struct foo array[] = {
    { ... }, /* item 1 */
    { ... }, /* item 2 */
    ...,
    { 0 } /* terminator */
};
for (i = 0; array[i].some_field; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Often you can find at least one field which is never `0`/`NULL` for normal elements, and if not, you can use some other special END value.

In code that I write, anything that involves compiletime-sized arrays is done with a macro like `ARRAY_COUNT` from Checkers's answer, and runtime-sized arrays always come with a size counter, in a struct with the array.

```
struct array_of_stuff {
    struct stuff *array;
    int count;   /* number of used elements */
    int length;  /* number of elements allocated */
};
```

The `length` field allows for easy batched resizing.

Answer (score 2):

### For C++, using std::vector

There's no real point in using a C-array. The std::vector has (almost) the same performance as a C array, and it will:

- grow as needed
- know its size
- verify you are really accessing the right memory (i.e. it could throw an exception if you go beyond its bounds)

And this is not even considering the generic algorithm associated with the std::vector.

### Now, using C

You can write it somewhat better at least in two ways. First, replacing a define with a true constant variable:

```
// #define MAXPLAYERS 4
const unsigned int MAXPLAYERS = 4 ;

int playerscores[MAXPLAYERS];

for(i=0;i<MAXPLAYERS;++i)
{
.... do something with each player
}
```

Using a true variable will offer your somewhat more type safety, and won't pollute the global scope. To minimize dependancies, you can even declare the variables in the header, and define them in a source:

```
/* header.h */
extern const unsigned int MAXPLAYERS ;
extern int playerscores[] ;

/* source.c */
const unsigned int MAXPLAYERS = 4
int playerscores[MAXPLAYERS];

/* another_source.c */
#include "header.h"

for(i=0;i<MAXPLAYERS;++i)
{
.... do something with each player
}
```

This way, you'll be able to change the size of the array in one source, without needing recompilation of all the sources using it. The downside is that MAXPLAYERS is not anymore known at compile time (but, is this really a downside?)

Note that your second type of array cannot grow dynamically. The sizeof is (at least in C++) evaluated at compile time. For growing arrays, malloc/realloc/free is the way to go in C, and std::vector (or any other generic STL container) is the way to go in C++.

Answer (score 1):

For C, I would suggest realloc to bring in new variables dynamically. If you are doing something statically, I would suggest keeping with the #define. I'm not sure if I'd call that best practice, but, today, that's how I would practice it.

The C++ best practice is to use stl::vector. [A reference here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/)

Answer (score 1):

I almost always use a wrapper class (MFC CArray, stl vector, etc.) unless there's a specific reason not too. There's not much overhead, you get a lot of debug checking, you can dynamically size, getting the size is easy, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to also read [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95500/can-this-macro-be-converted-to-a-function) - many solutions to the array size problem that *are* portable.

I especially like the `_countof` (cfr. Brian R. Bondy's answer) - Pulitzer for the inventor of that name!

Answer (score 0):

Addition to the answers so far, if you are using T[] arrays in C++:
Use template argument deduction to deduce the array size. It's much safer:

`template<int N> void for_all_objects(MYSTRUCT_DEF[N] myobjects)`

Your `sizeof(mystruct)/sizeof(MYSTRUCT_DEF)` expression fails quite silently if you change mystruct to a malloc'ed/new'ed `MYSTRUCT_DEF*`. `sizeof(mystruct)` then becomes `sizeof(MYSTRUCT_DEF*)`, which often is smaller than `sizeof(MYSTRUCT_DEF)`, and you'll have a loopcount of 0. It will seem like the code is simply not executed, which can be quite perplexing. The template declaration above will give you a clear compiler error instead ("mystruct is not an array")