# The Length of envp in C

Tags: c

In the proccess of learning C, I'm trying to write a program that accepts one of your environment variable as input, and outputs its value.

The question is, is there any way to know the length of envp? I mean, how many envp is there? I'm aware that it is a char** - an array of string. And [finding the size of array in C is problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089071/array-length-in-c) already. What can I do to know the size of envp?

Please just provide direction, not the concrete answer (or code).

Comment: `envp` is a `char**`, but it's not an "array of string". It's a pointer to the first element of an array of pointers, each of which is a pointer to (the first character of) a string -- except for the last, which is a null pointer and therefore doesn't point to anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's terminated by a NULL pointer.  You have to count it if you want to know the length.

Comment: Or, in the OP's case, you could just iterate with your terminating condition as `envp[i] == NULL`. You'll have to iterate over the elements to find the one you want anyway, you don't really _need_ the length for that.

Comment: @Chris I wasn't sure how explicit to be when the question specifically asked for a hint.  I guess now that the OP is satisfied I could edit for future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

the value of `argv[argc] == NULL` that should give you a clue.

Comment: That requires faith in consistency: that the POSIX environment vector is structured like the ISO C agrument vector.  One's faith in consistency is severely tested by software on a daily basis. :) :)

Answer (score 2):

You should look into `getenv()`. It's more portable than manipulating envp, because environments like plan9 implement the environment differently, while preserving the behavior of this function.

Comment: Yes, but `getenv()` can't tell you which environment variables are defined. If you already know the name of the variable, `getenv()` is great; if not, you need to traverse the data structure that `envp` points to.