# Understanding array size in C

Tags: c

I know this is a very basic question in C, so I apologize beforehand if this is naive: I'm just learning the basics a few days in.

```
int main() {

    // initialize the variables
    int num_whitespaces, num_other;
    int num_digits[10];
    printf("%lu", sizeof(num_digits));

}
```

This prints `40`, which seems odd to me. Why wouldn't this print `10`, which would be the length of the array in javascript or so.

Comment: I have no knowledge about `C` but I know that size of `int` is 32 bits (4 bytes).

Comment: Did you try already searching for similar questions? Probably it's because it returns a size of array (all it's elements), not just length - amount of elements. So it seems like int is 4 bytes in this case

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please search the existing questions before posting. It's unlikely you'll be encountering any problems that someone hasn't already solved many times over. See [ask].

Comment: @VladimirSerykh that's completely wrong. `int` in C must be at least 16 bits, otherwise the standard doesn't mandate a fixed size because C is supposed to be portable. So for example `int` will be 18-bit on an 18-bit architecture

Comment: @Shared you're also invoking undefined behavior because you used the wrong format specifier. [To print a `size_t` (which is the result of `sizeof`) use `%zu`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof` returns the size in memory. Not the length of something.

Same for C++ and this link has the same example :) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

```
size of empty class:              1
size of pointer:                  8
size of array of 10 int:         40
size of array of 10 int (2):     40
length of array of 10 int:       10
length of array of 10 int (2):   10
size of the Derived:              8
size of the Derived through Base: 4
```

Getting the length is pretty difficult in C: [array_length in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089071/array-length-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

[`sizeof` returns the size of an object in **bytes**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof)

An `int` is 4 bytes. `sizeof(int[10])` is 40.

Comment: what would be the best way then to get the length of an array (of any type) and not its size?

Comment: canonical way: sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])