# Unexplained error in C++ parser source code

Tags: c++, arrays, parsing, for-loop, runtime-error

This is the function that checks the name of the function entered by the user into the interpreter/parser I am making, compares it with the array of functions, and executes the corresponding C++ function. It works fine as long as the user enters a correct function name, but the interpreter ends with some unexplained runtime error if there is no function of the name the user entered, even though I programmed it to print "Undefined Function" and then carry on the parse loop:

```
void parser::eval_cmd(std::string& exp, pro::command fset[])
{
    expr = exp;
    exp_ptr = (char*) expr.c_str();

    bool found = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)sizeof(fset); i++)
    {
        if (fset[i].check(expr))
        {
            found = true;
            exp_ptr = (char*)expr.c_str() + (fset[i].name.size() - 1);
            if (fset[i].cmd)
                fset[i].cmd(eval_args());
            break;
        }

    }

    if (!found) err::show(err::UNDEFINED);
}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: By unexplained error, do you mean `err::show(err::UNDEFINED);` has been executed?

Comment: @Shahbaz the reason I called it an "unexplained" error was to make people understand that I am **not** talking about my own error.

Comment: expr = exp; this line is not making a deep copy of the original string (std::string implement reference counting). Than you cast away the costness of the underlying char*. There are good reason why c_str() return a const char*. You shouldn't use std::string in this way.

Comment: Also, `expr` and `exp_ptr` are undeclared. Also `exp_ptr` is set, but never used, in this function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is `(int)sizeof(fset)`.  That gives you the size of a pointer, in bytes, not the number of elements in the passed-in `fset` array.

You need some other way of determining how many elements are in the array, perhaps by passing in another arg, by using an `std::` container instead of an array, or by NULL-terminating the array.

For example, changing your function definition slightly:

```
void parser::eval_cmd(std::string& exp, const std::vector<pro::command>& fset)
{
    ...

    for (int i = 0; i < fset.size(); i++)
    {
        ...
```

The remainder of the code is unchanged.

---

**EDIT**: My best advice is to use `std::map<string, pro::command>` and allow `map` to manage the lookup algorithm, or `std::vector<pro::comand>` and use the above algorithm unchanged. You can measure the memory performance, but I expect that the only overhead of `vector` over array is the overhead of a `new`ed array over a static array.

If you do reach the conclusion not to use standard containers, here is my 2nd-best advice:

```
void parser::eval_cmd(std::string& exp, pro::command fset[], size_t count)
{
    ...

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
```

Presumably the caller knows (or can determine) the number of elements in the fset array. (See [Can this macro be converted to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95500/can-this-macro-be-converted-to-a-function/95896#95896) for help with that.)

Comment: +1. The question is tagged "C++", but it is very C-like code. Using an STL container might help.

Comment: +1. Thanks it is working perfectly now. But the reason I was trying to avoid the STL (and other memory consuming features and libs) was that it may cause overhead for the interpreter. What do you suggest? Is this just unnecessary optimising or will it cause performance issues later on?

Comment: @IntermediateHacker do you really think that home made code is faster then a standard library algorithm? Did you profile it?

Comment: @Alessandro Teruzzi, did he say faster? Read his comment again: _and other memory consuming features and libs_

Answer (score 2):

I see an immediate error, although without seeing more of the code, I
can't say for sure what the symptoms might be.  You're loop control
condition uses `sizeof(fset)`: `fset` is a pointer, so the value will
always be the same (typically 4 or 8, depending on whether you are in 32
bit or 64 bit mode).  I `fset` has less members, then you'll have
undefined behavior, and if it has more, you'll not check for any of the
later functions.

My recommendation would be to use an `std::map` for `fset`, and skip the
loop completely.

Comment: +1 for `std::map<std::string, pro::command>`. Excellent choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
..., pro::command fset[])
```

is equivalent to

```
..., pro::command *fset)
```

So when you do, `sizeof(fset)`, it calculates the `sizeof(command*)` and not the actual `sizeof(command)`. If you are unaware of the `fset[]` size then you can write a `template` wrapper:

```
template<unsigned int SIZE>  // <--- finds the sizeof fset
void parser::eval_cmd_array(std::string& exp, pro::command (&fset)[SIZE])
{
  void parser::eval_cmd(exp, fset, SIZE);  // <--- pass the size as 3rd param
}
```

Now you have got the array size in your original function;

```
void parser::eval_cmd(std::string& exp, pro::command fset[], unsigned int sizeof_fset)
{                                                          //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
 //...
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof_fset; i++)
 //...  ^^^^^^^^ let it be unsigned :)
}
```