# why does C++ forbid the declaration of a parameter with no type?

Tags: c++, arrays, types, ambiguity

I would like to have the following method as a generic method for any array,

```
int arrayLength(`anyType` array[])
{
    return sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
}
```

However it appears C++ doesn't allow any ambiguity of types at all,

why is this, and how should I go about getting around it?

Comment: `template<typename T, std::size_t N> std::size_t arrayLength(T (&)[N]) { return N; }`

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415524/common-array-length-macro-for-c

Comment: another related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95500/can-this-macro-be-converted-to-a-function

Comment: @ilgjarn Would it be possible for you to explain your code to me in full, i.e. spell it out like i'm a complete dummy, because I'd really like to understand everything that it is doing, Thanks

Comment: @Sebastian : It appears to me to be explained in detail in the very answer you linked to.

Comment: @ilgjarn I don't understand the (&)[N] part, I can't find an explanation for this anywhere

Comment: @Sebastian : `T (&)[N]` is an unnamed argument that is a reference to a `T[N]` (i.e., an array of `T` of length `N`). Name the argument if that makes it easier to understand, e.g. `T (&arr)[N]`.

Comment: @ilgjarn why is the named argument in brackets, and why is it simply referenced and not just passed in normally though? Thanks

Comment: @Sebastian : C-arrays cannot be passed by value without decaying into a pointer so the only way to deduce the C-array's size is to pass by reference. If one were using `std::array<>` or `boost::array<>` then this wouldn't be an issue (hint hint).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6980/discussion-between-sebastian-troy-and-ildjarn)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because types have to be pushed onto the stack and then popped back off, and the `sizeof` one type is not equal to the `sizeof` another type.

If the size of types being passed on the stack between functions is not fixed or known in advance, how can the compiler compile a function?

The solutions to this problem -- as others have noted -- is templates and macros, both of which dynamically generate code -- which is then, in turn, compiled -- at compile-time, appearing to "*solve*" the problem, but really only obviating or distracting you from it by offloading the work onto the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual C++ there's a `__countof()` construct that does the same. It's implemented as a template for C++ compiling and as a macro for C. The C++ version errors out if used on a pointer (as opposed to a true array), the C version does not.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're really asking is "Why does C++ insist on static typing?"

The answer: because it's easier to write a compiler that generates small, fast programs if the language uses static typing. And that's the purpose of C++: creating small, fast programs whose complexity would be relatively unmanageable if written in C.

When I say "small", I'm including the size of any required runtime libraries.